# Create a value observer and update textview/list view from any activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-listview, android-service, notifydatasetchanged

**Setup**

I have a textview in an activity. This is essentially a notification count view. Clicking on this opens a dialog with a list view that has the notifications. Now I can receive notifications no matter in which activity I am. The textview exists in the home fragment of the main activity. There are many such fragments and various activities in the app.

**Where does the data come from**

There is a service which downloads from a web services, some data and puts it into a global array list say `Constants.arraylist`. The notification count is stored into another global variable say `Constants.notifcount`. This service can run anytime. Now I need to update the textview and listview in the above setup with the updated data no matter in which activity I am when this background service finishes running. I cant bind the service to the main activity for various business logic reasons

SO the textview should update itself to the latest `Constants.notifcount` and the listview should update to the latest `Constants.arraylist`

NOTE--> I know global variables are bad design and I'll figure out better ways to do it once I finish this POC.

**Questions**

> Is it possible
>
> 1.) To Create a listener on the variables such that no matter where I am these two data fields can be updated immediately after the service
>   runs.
>
> 2.) Is there a better way to do this ? Or better yet what is the industry best practice for creating a run time notifier like this? (Dataset observables? Loopers?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whereever your textview is, register a broadcast receiver. When the notification count changes, broadcast it via the receiver and update your textview. You could even subclass textview, add a run-time broadcast receiver (that is, register it on onAttachedToWindow and unregister it onDetachedFromWindow). Then no matter where the textview is, whenever the service is running it'll be able to notify the textview.

Comment: Great thanks. This is what I did, but wanted to see if there were better ways to solve the problem with observers. Ill mark this as accepted for now :)